# Typed function for dispatching functions through a Record

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

```
const dispatch = {
  'A': (arg: { a0: number }) => { },
  'B': (arg: { b0: string, b1: number }) => { }
}

function Dispatcher<???>(key: ???, arg: ???) {
  dispatch[key](arg); 
}
function Dispatcher2<K extends keyof typeof dispatch>
(key: K, arg: Parameters<typeof dispatch[K]>[0]) {
    dispatch[key](arg);// passing arg fails type checking
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgSwgBwIZWACxgXhgbwFgAoGGAcgEFyAuGAClTvxlQAY6wBXAWwCMApgCcYAXwCUuAHwExAGhJlyAIVoM%20zGHw4xoQhGADmcrQEZOvQSInTZokveIkoAT2QCYlIYYA8AaRgBAA8oATA4CBgAawEXEAAzGFd3BPgkNAxMGTwABVQhVB4BUKEIH2SBVMQUdCwAbT8AXSk6tkaSZzcPL0NKXE9vHypyGQB6UZhQISEBYCgAGxcYZARgKMj8w0jU4c73AcNlfp6h1TGJqZm5xeXV9dZvbcSVcg6nYniuMDmEcBgAEXStUwwn8gRCYQi0ViqQqVSBmSk9BiLjofhMmzoeQKRRKZThiWqGXqTRabUkRFIZDSNUydRRjUY3nEAG4HG8gA)

There are several ways to allow only the correct combinations of `key` and `arg` into `Dispatcher`. However, I can never get TypeScript to understand that it's ok to pass the `arg` into the function call.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be put in the category of *"correlated union"* problems. When indexing `dispatch` with `key`, the compiler computes a union of functions which is only callable with an intersection of all parameters. The relationship between `dispatch[key]` and `arg` is essentially lost.

But there is a specific way to rewrite the types as described in [PR#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to make the compiler understand the correlation.

We have to change the typing of `dispatch` so that it uses a *mapped type*. The type `DispatchRecord` acts as a lookup type for the parameter types.

```
type DispatchRecord = { 
  A: { a0: number }
  B: { b0: string, b1: number }
}

const dispatch: { 
  [K in keyof DispatchRecord]: (arg: DispatchRecord[K]) => void 
} = {
  'A': (a) => { },
  'B': (b) => { }
}
```

The function itself stays generic over `K`. To type `key` and `arg`, we use a rest parameter. The type of the rest parameter is mapped type which computes a tuple consisting of two elements, one for `key` and one for `arg`. This mapped type is then indexed by `K`.

```
function Dispatcher<K extends keyof DispatchRecord>(...[key, arg]: {
  [P in K]: [P, DispatchRecord[P]]
}[K]) {
    dispatch[key](arg)
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAEQJYGcoEMwGMAWAlGLAewCcATOAXjgG85Q44BBALlrnQAY2A7AVwC2AIxgk4AXwZwAQmzpDucFGBJIeAcwA0cIQEZegkWMkgToYj2VwyqDNhxy4AbQDScNXADWMCEQBmiLaYuATE5AC6bAAU6CTqbMhowfiEpGSu4QCUVAB8cABuREgU4lS0UgDkTBXR6NmUeXTimpXSNXBRQvWNEqBmIH58PFhgSEQ8gUn2ogA8bjAAHmAwPGQoXj7+k3YhqeQ5UQB0x07eENqx6pHlIIxOAAruEy7XD9qJOylh6ffh4X0ZbI0KSMGxTXCnHzhGJxTJ9IA)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Tbh, I was hoping that everything could be inferred from the dispatcher object (I'm sort of writing a library). Would maybe a Map object work? Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: From my understanding, it *has* to be a mapped type for this to work.